# How to calculate $\int_{\Delta_n}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j}\,dx_1\cdots dx_n$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus

Let $f:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$ be smooth, $1\leq j\leq n$, and let $\Delta_n=\{x\mid\sum_{i=1}^nx_i\leq1;x_i\geq0\}\subset\mathbb R^n$ denote the standard $n$-simplex in $\mathbb R^n$. I'm trying to prove that
$$\int_{\Delta_n}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j}\,dx_1\cdots dx_n\\=\int_{\Delta_{n-1}}f(x_1,\dots,1-\sum_{i\neq j}x_i,\dots,x_n)\,dx_1\cdots\widehat{dx_j}\cdots dx_n-\int_{\Delta_{n-1}}f(x_1,\dots,0,\dots,x_n)\,dx_1\cdots\widehat{dx_j}\cdots dx_n,$$
where the integrals are Lebesgue integrals (not that it makes much of a difference, I suppose).
This makes sense to me intuitively, however I'm having difficulty showing it rigorously. My thoughts went something like this

> Write $\int_{\Delta_n}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j}$ as $\int_{\mathbb R^n}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j}\cdot\chi$, where $\chi$ is the characteristic function of $\Delta_n$. Then by Fubini
> $$\int_{\mathbb R^n}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j}\cdot\chi=\int_{\mathbb R^{n-1}}\Big(\int_{\mathbb R}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j}(x_1,\dots,\widehat{x_j},\dots,x_n)\cdot\chi(x_1,\dots,\widehat{x_j},\dots,x_n)\,dx_j\Big)\,dx_1\cdots\widehat{dx_j}\cdots dx_n.$$
> The outer integral "should" become $\int_{\Delta_{n-1}}$ because that's where the coordinates $x_1,\dots,\widehat{x_j},\dots,x_n$ "may vary" with $x_j$ fixed, while the inner integral "should" become $\int_{0}^{1-\sum_{i\neq j}x_i}$ because that's where the coordinate $x_j$ "may vary" with the rest fixed. The rest follows by the fundamental theorem of calculus.

How do I make this precise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write the integral as
$$
\int_{\Delta_n} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j}dx^1 \cdots dx^n = \int_{\Delta_{n-1}}\left(\int_0^{1 - \sum_{i \neq j}x_i} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} dx^r\right)dx^1\cdots\widehat{dx^j}\cdots dx^n
$$
Where $\Delta_{n-1}$ is the subset of $\Delta_n$ with $x_j = 0$. Then from the fundamental theorem of calculus, we have that
$$
\int_{\Delta_n} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j}dx^1 \cdots dx^n = \int_{\Delta_{n-1}}f(x_1, \dots, 1 - \sum_{i \neq j}x_i, \dots, x^n) - f(x_1, \dots, 0, \dots, x_n) dx^1 \cdots \widehat{dx^j} \cdots dx^n.
$$
To completely justify this, it is sufficient to justify the first step, as the rest is just integration with respect to one variable. Let's assume that
$$
\int_{\Delta_n} \left|\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_i}\right| = M < \infty
$$
Then as you said, from Fubini's theorem we have that
$$
\int_{\Delta^n}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} = \int_{\mathbb R^{n-1}} \left(\int_\mathbb R \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j} \chi_{\Delta_n}dx^j\right)dx^1 \dots \widehat{dx^j} \dots dx^n
$$
where $\chi_X$ is the characteristic function on $X \subseteq \mathbb R^n$. So now we just need to manipulate the characteristic function inside the first integral. The main thing to note is that
$$
\chi_{\Delta_n} = \chi_{\Delta_{n-1}}\chi_{x_j \in [0, 1 - \sum_{j \neq j} x_i]},
$$
where $\chi_{\Delta_{n-1}}$ only depends on $\{x_i, i \neq j\}$. So we have
$$
\int_{\Delta^n}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} = \int_{\mathbb R^{n-1}} \left(\int_\mathbb R \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j} \chi_{\Delta_{n-1}}\chi_{[0, 1 - \sum_{j \neq j} x_i]}dx^j\right)dx^1 \dots \widehat{dx^j} \dots dx^n
$$
And we then note that $\chi_{\Delta_{n-1}}$ has no $x_j$ dependence and so can be pulled out of the integral. Hence
$$
\int_{\Delta^n}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} = \int_{\mathbb R^{n-1}}\chi_{\Delta_{n-1}} \left(\int_\mathbb R \chi_{[0, 1 - \sum_{j \neq j} x_i]}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j} dx^j\right)dx^1 \dots \widehat{dx^j} \dots dx^n.
$$

Comment: How to rigorously prove the integral can be written this way is pretty much what my question was.

Comment: Sorry I misread your question - I've added some more justification.

Comment: How do you write $\chi_{\Delta_n} = \chi_{\Delta_{n-1}}\chi_{x_j \in [0, 1 - \sum_{j \neq j} x_i]}$, the last function doesn't make a lot of sense to me.

Comment: If $(x_1, \dots, \hat x_j \dots,  x_n)$ are fixed then $g = \chi_{x_j \in [0, 1 - \sum_{i \neq j} x_i]}$ is just a standard characteristic function on the variable $x_j$. If we allow the $x_i$ to vary, and the $(x_i)$ are in $\Delta^{n-1}$ then $g = 1$ if and only if $(x_1, \dots, x_n) \in \Delta^n$, this follows from the definition of $\Delta^n$

Comment: I think I finally worked it out, thanks.